# Double click on Youtube Chromeless player for full-screen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, youtube

I'm trying to add a double-click event to a chromeless player for youtube. This doesn't work, because the player is on top, I guess:

```
stage.doubleClickEnabled = true;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,fullScreenSwitch);
```

When I add it to the sprite in which the player is loaded, it works, but then I can't click on the player (to click ads away for example).

Anyone an idea?

Comment: did you try to pass click events to the player from your sprite? and what does `fullScreenSwitch` do? is it possible to access the players `stage.displayState` directly?

Comment: Hello, I tried, but then I have to disable mousechildren, otherwise it doesn't work. But then, the clicks in the youtube player won't work (clicking ads away). I can't get both working.